# MySQL moving average over past 14 days

Tags: mysql, moving-average, mysql-5.6

in my MySQL database I have the following view (originally combining 2 data tables) called MYDATA.

TABLE MYDATA

| user | myDate | items |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 17 | 2020-01-01 | 1.0 |
| 22 | 2020-01-01 | 6.0 |
| 17 | 2020-01-02 | 3.2 |
| 17 | 2020-01-04 | 4.0 |
| 17 | 2020-01-08 | 1.0 |
| 17 | 2020-01-09 | 6.2 |
| 22 | 2020-01-09 | 4.0 |
| 17 | 2020-01-10 | 5.3 |

As you can see NOT all dates (column myDate) contain items. For a selected user (i.e. user 17) I need to calculate the moving average of sold items (column items) over past 14 days ("this" day included) for ALL DATES (i.e. including 2020-01-03 which is not included in the MYDATA table). So basically I want to obtain the following:

| user | myDate | result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 17 | 2020-01-01 | (avg last 14 days) |
| 17 | 2020-01-02 | (avg last 14 days) |
| 17 | 2020-01-03 | (avg last 14 days) |
| ... | ... | ... |
| 17 | 2020-12-30 | (avg last 14 days) |
| 17 | 2020-12-31 | (avg last 14 days) |

Feel free to play with it in SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/02cc94/1

If needed I have a table "calendar" containing all the year's dates as well.

TABLE CALENDAR

| myDate |
| --- |
| 2020-01-01 |
| 2020-01-02 |
| 2020-01-03 |
| 2020-01-04 |
| 2020-01-05 |
| 2020-01-06 |

How can I proceed please? Thanks for any help. I've been stuck on this issue for months.

Comment: IMPORTANT! I only have the VERSION() 5.5.62-38.14 and am not sure if I can upgrade it. 

Comment: *Feel free to play with it in SQLFiddle* Provide desired output for this fiddle.

Comment: What is maximal possible period-in-interest length (in days) or the amount of rows in CALENDAR table?

Comment: Calendar contains all the dates from 2014 to today (I need to calculate the moving average for various years). Also note that I do need not an average itself, but in fact a sum (over past 14 days) of items divided by 14. (Like an average including null values).

Comment: Please provide desired output for your fiddle data strictly (with explanations for 2-3 rows). PS. And why did you make the `items` INTEGER in the fiddle whereas assign decimal values?

Comment: sorry, I was unable to format this comment as a table, but the result for user=17 should be the following: 2020-01-01: 0.1; 2020-01-02: 0.3; 2020-01-03: 0.3

Answer (score 0):

Look for

```sql
SELECT user, t1.myDate, SUM(t2.items) / 14 avg_items
FROM calendar t1
JOIN test t2 ON t2.myDate BETWEEN t1.myDate - INTERVAL 13 DAY and t1.myDate
GROUP BY t2.user, t1.myDate
ORDER BY 1,2
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=fd7f17d5ac45531fe031344db60e0635) - MySQL8-specific construction (CTE) is used for `calendar` table generation only.